# Largest SKI output in less than 200 combinators

Tags: number, code-challenge, busy-beaver, combinatory-logic

## The Challenge

Create an **terminating** expression in [SKI Combinator Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) in less than 200 combinators (S, K, I) that reduces to the expression with the most combinators.

There will be no limit on how many parenthesis/applications can be used.

## SKI

SKI expressions are created using S, K, I and parenthesis. They are reduced like so:

```
(((Sx)y)z) => ((xz)(yz))
((Kx)y) => x
(Ix) => x
```

When parenthesis with more than two expressions are in an expression, they are assumed to be nested to the left.

```
(xyz) = ((xy)z)
```

## Scoring

The score will be the number of combinators in the output, the goal is for this to be as large as possible.

## Examples

Here is an example of a reduction in SKI using the rules stated above.

```
(((SI)I)(((SI)I)S))
((I(((SI)I)S))(I(((SI)I)S)))
((((SI)I)S)(I(((SI)I)S)))
(((IS)(IS))(I(((SI)I)S)))
((S(IS))(I(((SI)I)S)))
((SS)(I(((SI)I)S)))
((SS)(((SI)I)S))
((SS)((IS)(IS)))
((SS)(S(IS)))
((SS)(SS))
```

So the expression `(((SI)I)(((SI)I)S))` scores 4.

Comment: you should include explanations about things relevant to the challenge in the challenge rather than as an external resource. also, i can't remember if ski combinators can fall into an infinite cycle, but if so, you should probably clarify the rules about that (if not then sorry)

Comment: @hyper-neutrino I clarified the expression needs to terminate, and explaind the reduction.

Comment: @Noodle9 I added an example, hopefully that will clear some things up. If that doesn't, the wikipedia article might help. Tell me if there is anything specific that is confusing in this.

Comment: Much better, retracted close vote.

Comment: @DLosc I replaced [math].

Comment: A much better answer than mine could be drawn out of the number `n` in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235867/78410).

Comment: Reminds me of the [Luring Lottery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonia_dilemma#Luring_Lottery) of 1983: "mathematical expressions designed to evaluate to the largest possible number in the limited space allowed [a postcard]."

Comment: I like this challenge a lot but I wish the 200 combinator limit was a lot lower - I think you could get mind-bogglingly astronomically huge scores even if it was 20 or less. (But don't change it now.)

Comment: @N.Virgo Yeah, I wasn't really sure how few combinators would be needed to make this size of number.

Comment: Hmm... I'm aware of Adam Goucher's \$\Xi\$ function, this seems somewhat similar.

Answer (score 21):

## 44 combinators, score: \$\approx f_{\omega+1}(3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3)\$

```haskell
(S (S (K S) (S S K)) (K I)) arrow_diag (S (S (K S) K) (S (S (K S) K) I)) S K
where arrow_diag = S (S (S I (K (S (S (K S) (S (K (S I)) K)) (K I)))) (S (K (S I)) K)) I
```

This reduces to an expression of `S (S (S (...(S K)...)))` which contains `n` copies of `S`, where `n` is the value obtained by repeatedly applying `arrow_diag` function (a 1-input function that diagonalizes over the Knuth's up arrow notation, explained below) `arrow_diag 3` times to the number 3.

**Edit:** Fixed the `arrow_diag` function, and changed 2 to 3 because I found `arrow_diag 2` was just 4. Though I guess `arrow_diag (arrow_diag (arrow_diag (arrow_diag 2)))` would still be insanely large.

The first idea is that we will construct a Church numeral for a very large natural number `n`, which is `\f. \x. f (f (f ... f x))` (`f` applied `n` times to `x`), and then force it by applying `S` and `K` to it. Then the normal form would be `S (S (... S K))` which has exactly `n+1` combinators.

Now, let's find a way to build large numbers. A good start point is the deceptively short power function

```haskell
-- x^y
exp x y = y x
exp = \x. \y. y x
```

Then we can repeat the partially applied `exp` to build tetration and beyond (corresponding to \$x\uparrow\uparrow y\$, \$x\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow y\$ and so on):

```haskell
-- x^^y = x^(x^...(x^x))
tet x y = y (x^) 1
tet = \x. \y. y (\y. y x) 1
-- x^^^y = x^^(x^^...)
quad x y = y (x^^) 1
quad = \x. \y. y (\y. y (\y. y x) 1) 1
-- in general:
arrow<N> = \x. \y. y (arrow<N-1> x) 1
```

Then we can try converting these into SKI. Since the next arrow notation involves a partially applied previous one, just partially converting gives helpful insights.

```haskell
exp = \x. \y. y x
= \x. S I (K x)
tet = \x. \y. y (\y. y x) 1
= \x. \y. y (S I (K x)) I
= \x. S (\y. y (S I (K x))) (K I)
= \x. S (S I (K (S I (K x)))) (K I)
quad = \x. \y. y (\y. y (\y. y x) 1) 1
= \x. \y. y (S (S I (K (S I (K x)))) (K I)) I
= ...
```

Here we can spot a pattern. Here comes the beauty of pure lambda calculus: we can extract arbitrary subexpression into a lambda. Meanwhile, we can change 1 to `y` to get a higher number and save 1 combinator.

```haskell
\x. \y. y (someexpr) 1
= \x. S (S I (K someexpr)) (K I)
= \x. (\e. S (S I (K e)) (K I)) someexpr

\x. \y. y (someexpr) y
= \x. S (S I (K someexpr)) I
= \x. (\e. S (S I (K e)) I) someexpr

tet' = \x. 1 (\e. S (S I (K e)) I) (S I (K x))
arrow<n> = \x. n (\e. S (S I (K e)) I) (S I (K x))
```

Here `arrow<n> x y` (roughly) calculates \$x \uparrow^{n+1} y\$.

Now we diagonalize over the arrow notation, by using `x`, the input value, instead of `n`.

```haskell
arrow_diag2 = \x. x (\e. S (S I (K e)) I) (S I (K x))
= S (S I (K (S (S (K S) (S (K (S I)) K)) (K I)))) (S (K (S I)) K)
```

But it is still a binary function that calculates (roughly) \$x \uparrow^{x+1} y\$, so let's make it unary:

```haskell
arrow_diag = \x. arrow_diag2 x x
= S arrow_diag2 I
= S (S (S I (K (S (S (K S) (S (K (S I)) K)) (K I)))) (S (K (S I)) K)) I
```

This has just **22** combinators. To get a non-trivial number (don't forget, we're also adding `S K` at the end to get a deterministic combinator count), we evaluate

```haskell
arrow_diag 3 arrow_diag 3 S K
= (\x y. x y x y) arrow_diag 3 S K
= (S (S (K S) (S S K)) (K I)) arrow_diag (S (S (K S) K) (S (S (K S) K) I)) S K
```

which has just **44** combinators but evaluates to an... extremely large number that I don't know how to express correctly.

Comment: It sounds like your number can probably be expressed in terms of the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), if that's any help.

Comment: If `arrow_diag` takes in two numbers to return a number, how is it that `arrow_diag 3` will return a complete number?

Comment: @nph The current `arrow_diag` does take one number and evaluates to a number. The one that takes two numbers is the previous version (`arrow_diag2` in the current explanation).

Comment: I think this number is about f_(omega+1)(3^^^^3) in [The fast-growing hierarchy](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Introduction_to_the_fast-growing_hierarchy)